# Debugging CommonServiceLocator.ActivationExeption in MVVMLight

Tags: vb.net, mvvm-light, ioc-container, navigationservice

I'm trying to use Ioc in MVVMLight.
SimpleIoc works fine with my ViewModel, but not the NavigationService.

I've drawn a blank googling the error, but suspect the problem might be in my conversion of various C# snippets to VB.net ?

[image: error msg]

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly solving your problem, but: You are using service locator technique, which is considered anti-pattern and it is against MVVM principles. Correct way is to get *INavigationService* instance in view model's constructor parameter. Maybe you will get somewhere by doing it like I am saying.

Comment: Interesting. Why is an anti-pattern included in MVVMLight ? (I'm new to this;) Any suggestions on a good article that explains how to use it ?

Comment: @Maf There are countless articles about MVVM pattern. It is anti-pattern for example because by using service locator, you hide dependencies of class, that are otherwise mandatory in constructor. It is better to pass 10 dependencies in constructor instead of 1 service locator. That locator is not guaranteed to have them registered so unexpected runtime errors can occur if you use service locator pattern.